# How to pass parameters to a vm file (Velocity) from another vm file (velocity) through java script?

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, velocity

My review.vm file contain a table of records. When user click one of those records in the table ,I want to pass id and data of that record as parameters and call update.vm file from  review.vm file through java script.
the java script function in review.vm looks below:

```
  function callUpdateVm(id,data) {
    var vmcall = "update.vm";
    window.location.href = vmcall;
    }
```

may i know how to pass the id and date also to update.vm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using velocity tools, then your javascript can be like:

```
var vmcall = "update.vm?id=" + id;
```

and on the server side, your `update.vm` file can access HTTP query parameters using the [`ParameterTool`](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/tools-summary.html#ParameterTool):

```
#set($id = $params.id)
```

This being said, you must of course be careful about access rules to your `update.vm` URL if you aren't inside a protected area, otherwise malicious users could trigger unwanted updates.